# No indexing in SQL tables (neither clustered nor non-clustered)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, indexing, non-clustered-index

There is a stored procedure which has gets data from table `tbl_SPP` and makes joins with necessary tables. The table `tbl_SPP` has 27 million rows. It has 4 non-clustered indexes.

I have to improve the performance of the query. The cost of the query is 99%.
I tried adding a clustered index at the time of executing the procedure. But it takes more time than when it was not there.

I dropped all 4 non-clustered indexes from `tbl_SPP` and the cost of the query is reduced to 47%. The plan is to drop the index at the being of procedure and re-create it at the end

Now my question is: what are the disadvantages of dropping all the non-clustered indexes from the table? Will it improve the performance of stored procedure at real time?

Comment: DBMS PRoduct is SQL Server

Comment: "I dropped all 4 non-clustered indexes from tbl_SPP and the cost of the query is reduced to 47%.". As the question indicates that this is a SELECT query you shouldn't be dropping indexes. Post both execution plans

Answer (score 0):

> what are the disadvantages of dropping all the non-clustered indexes from the table?

Other queries may be slower, and you have eliminated options and destroyed statistics.  Have you tried with a [columnstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2014) index?